# isPalindrome recursion string

Tags: python, string

why does this not work?
It works for False palindrome; however, for anything True it never returns True..
I don't understand why this function does not return True?
And how I should improve this same answer so that it returns True.

My logic was that after the function completes iterating through the entire string, it will return True.

```
def isPalindrome(string, i = 0):
    if i == len(string): 
        return True
    if string[i] != string[len(string)-1-i]:
        return False
    isPalindrome(string,i+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your last line:

```
isPalindrome(string,i+1)
```

That last line will eventually resolve to either `True` or `False` -- but how is *that* value being returned? *(It isn't.)*

Try:

```
return isPalindrome(string,i+1)
```

Comment: I don't understand though -- I thought I am returning True and False in the previous two conditions. So why is the return statement in the last line required? Sorry but can you please expand on why exactly though there is return True and False -- return is needed in the last line?

Comment: What would be your expectation, if neither of the previous two conditions apply? What value should the function return?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the visualization [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20isPalindrome%28string,%20i%20%3D%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3D%3D%20len%28string%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20if%20string%5Bi%5D%20!%3D%20string%5Blen%28string%29-1-i%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0A%20%20%20%20isPalindrome%28string,i%2B1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28isPalindrome%28%27abba%27%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

My hint would be check what you are returning (i.e. what does isPalindrome return).

If you want just the answer, it is [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20isPalindrome%28string,%20i%20%3D%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3D%3D%20len%28string%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20if%20string%5Bi%5D%20!%3D%20string%5Blen%28string%29-1-i%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0A%20%20%20%20return%20isPalindrome%28string,i%2B1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28isPalindrome%28%27abba%27%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)